# Activate links only for particular users

Tags: php

I have an interface which has a link to another page. I want this link to activate only for one user type. I have 5 user types declare at session creation. How should I do this?

Comment: please post your code so we can help you trace it. but ideally, you can get the user type on session, then it's a matter of javascript (or jquery) to control the hide and show of your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call the special usertype `special`.You say you have declared it at the start of the session.I am assuming you did it something like `$_SESSION['usertype'] = "special";`.
Now if you want to activate a link only if the `usertype` is `special`, do it as follows:

```
if($_SESSION['usertype'] == "special")
{
echo '<p><a href = "name.php">Special link</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work. I will try this.

Comment: Good, but missing one very important element.

Comment: What is that element?

Comment: Are you familiar with using sessions? @user2979226

Comment: @Fred -ii This code assumes that the user has session_start(); in his page.This code is only meant for the part where he has to selectively display links depending on the usertype.

Comment: One should **never assume** a person's coding knowledge. What if someone else visits this Question/Answer and doesn't know what to do? How many (countless) times have I seen people posting questions with session calls, but have no knowledge about `session_start();` THAT being the "missing element" ;-) @just_a_coder Concise and in-depth answers are beneficial for `all`.

Comment: session_start(); is already included on my page. I have that basic understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know php?

```
 if($_SESSION["user_type"] == "some"){
       //show the link
  }
```

Comment: this is right. then it's a matter of javascript manipulation to show and hide the divs.

Comment: Do you make it with js? Is this?

Comment: Good also, but you're missing an important element.

Comment: I know php but little bit of js. Any way i will try through this.